# size of qt code engine

Tags: qt4

I have few questions to clarify

1) Is there any limit on number of lines of code an qt application can contain?
2) Memory usage of qt frame work at runtime.
3) execution model of qt. mean to say i have thread in main application when event arises will the main thread forks another thread to handle events or events are handled by main thread it self???? what about rendering part. how does qt renders images/text

Answer (score 1):

```
* Qt libraries 4.7.1 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 319 MB)
* Qt libraries 4.7.1 for Windows (VS 2008, 228 MB)
* Qt libraries 4.7.1 for Linux/X11(202 MB)
* Qt libraries 4.7.1 for Mac
* Qt libraries 4.7.1 for embedded Linux (202 MB)
* Qt libraries 4.7.1 for Windows CE (236 MB)
* Qt libraries 4.7.1 for Symbian (265 MB)

* Qt SDK for Windows* (322 MB)
* Qt SDK for Linux/X11 32-bit** (422 MB)
* Qt SDK for Linux/X11 64-bit** (530 MB)
* Qt SDK for Mac (927 MB)
```

Comment: i just wanted to know is there any limit on number of lines of code an particular qt application can contain.!!!!!!

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that .  .

Comment: @rashmi - don't get angry if you can't phrase a question properly...

Answer (score 0):

> i just wanted to know is there any
>   limit on number of lines of code an
>   particular qt application can
>   contain.!!!!!!

First of all please read: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#intro

As far as I can tell there is no limit on the number of lines of code an application in any descent programming language can contain.

That being said there are very large projects written on top of Qt, for example the KDE project.

There is no chance you'll ever be able to get to a maximum lines of bytes of code for the platform.

Comment: @jinx, 1)is there any limit on number of lines an application contain if so what is the limit? 2)how much memory (on average) does the Qt Framework consume at runtime

Comment: @Rashmi - **EDIT** your question to reflect that - don't just keep adding comments....